# why is child's div height exceeding body

Tags: html, css, height

in my html, I have something like

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "main">
            <div> I'm 500px tall</div>
            <div> I'm xxxpx tall</div>
        </div>            
    </body>

</html>
```

and my css is like

```
head, body, #main{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

otherDivs{
    height: some number of px
}
```

display for everything are either block or inline, there is no float

positioning are either absolute or relative

and what happened was that the #main (&body&html which wraps it) height was not full page height (only around 2/3 of page height), and some divs contained in the #main actually exceed the main's height

I had this fixed by changing height:100% to min-height:100%
but could not understand why the elements would exceed their parent divs height, I'm 100% sure all height of the children divs are declared in px, would't #main automatically wrap them?

Comment: height 100% of the body and html would be the height of the browser window so when you set the height of main to 100% you are limiting it to the height of your browser window.  By setting min-height you say you want it to be a minimum of 100% but if it exceeds this (larger content than the window) then grow to fit

Comment: yes I was aware of that, but what I don't understand is that the #main actually did not stretch to the window height and causing child divs to exceed in height..

Comment: okay, I don't actually think you can set html and body to be height 100% as far as my knowledge of 100% height goes you need at least one parent to have an absolute amount of px set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `height:100%` for `#main`, use `overflow:hidden;` property